# Why isn't this script to delete part of my command history working on my computer?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

The script can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750650/how-to-delete-history-of-last-10-commands-in-shell

For convenience here it is:

```
for x in `seq $1 $2`
do
  history -d $1
done
```

I put this in my include directory (one which I've added to the PATH) where I run many other scripts I've written and work just fine.

This does not produce the desired result of deleting rows from my history, in fact it does nothing at all.

Any idea why the history command doesn't work? I'm wondering if it has something to do with the directories.

**Additional Info:**

I played around with the code and tried different variations. If I put an `echo` in front of the `history` command and run it, I get the following output:

```
cgravel@scspc578:~$ idelhistory 300 305
history -d 300
history -d 301
history -d 302
history -d 303
history -d 304
history -d 305
cgravel@scspc578:~$
```

So, to me, it seems like it should work perfectly. I can't figure out why. This script is being run from /$HOME/Scripts/ and it has been included in the PATH. I also tried running it with sudo and nothing changes.

Comment: That's how it was when I copied it. I didn't write this script, but everyone else seems to be pleased with it. In any case, I made the change you suggest and it still doesn't work

Comment: @John1024 If you read the comments on that answer the author of the post is very explicit that `$1` is correct.

Comment: @Klik Try replacing the backticks (\`) with a single quote ('). That resolved it for me.

Comment: Interesting... So I made the change you suggested and I now get an error, "history position out of range". I also tried running it using it's full path (it made no difference). Also I am sure that the history position is not out of range.... I have more than 400 items in my history.

Comment: @Klik Yeah, I got that same error - it would appear to be some form of error with the loop.

Comment: @Seth Actually, I see now that there are two answers to that question.  One (Barmar) uses `$1` and the other (Tyler) uses `$i`.  Both answers have an equal number of votes.  When someone here (who has enough time) resolves what is correct, those answers should be edited.

Comment: I tried rearranging it to echo $1 | xargs history -d; but xargs doesn't work with history for some reason.

Comment: `$1` is definitly wrong!! it has to be `$x`. you would try to remove the start number `$x` times.

Comment: @LittleByBlue That's what I thought at first. However, if you see the output I got from using echo in front of the history command with $1, you can see that it does do what the author intended (though it doesn't work for me).

Comment: @Klik Are you using dash or bash? Make sure it's bash.

Comment: @John1024 it is necessary that $1 be used in the for loop as the positional structure of history is not static, but is rather that of a vector. If you used $x, it would fail ~half-way through.

Comment: @Seth I'm using the terminal... I'm a pretty new Ubuntu user, I assumed that would be bash, but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Klik Doesn't really matter, I tested it in bash, same problem.

Comment: @Klik Sorry, I was definitly wrong. because if  you are deleteing `array[n]` then `array[n+1]` is now `array[n]`.

Comment: @joshumax In that case, it might be good if you submitted an edit for Tyler's answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one sentence: it doesn't work because you aren't calling it correctly.

First, since your script doesn't start with [`#!/bin/bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), it isn't actually a bash script. Which shell it is executed by depends on how you invoke it. When you invoke it from the bash command line, bash [forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) a new instance of itself (this has to happen to execute any external command anyway), and it's this new instance that executes the script. So the script is executed with the same settings (including the history so far) as the parent shell. It is executed with different [options](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin); in particular, history tracking is off for the commands in the script (which suits you, since otherwise it would add to the history that you want to modify).

Whether the bash instance executing the script has the [`HISTFILE` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTFILE) set depends on whether it was exported in the parent (which is a little weird). If it isn't exported and thus set in the child, then the child script won't save the modified history when it ends.

If `HISTFILE` is exported, then the child script will modify your history file. However, unless you've configured your interactive shell to [reload the history after every command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-history-when-pressing-up-in-bash-shared-between-shell), the modified history will only be picked up by newly started instances of bash.

If you want to run a shell snippet that affects the current shell instance, **you must run that shell in the current shell instance, instead of running it as a subprocess**. You'd run into a similar problem if you wanted to do other things that affect the shell process itself, such as changing directories, setting variables, etc. Use the [`.` (“dot”) or `source`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-_002e) builtin to run a script in the current shell process.

```
. idelhistory 300 365
```

Alternatively, you could define this as a function in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/history.def#n203 and http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/history.def#n180 shows that bash has a strang way of reading, caching, and removing history that doesn't just directly write to HISTFILE during a delete and open HISTFILE during a read.

Comment: The last part of this answer (defining a function) would seem to be the simplest and most logical approach.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: It seems that there still seem to be some problems on certain machines that run this script. Another (and perhaps the best) way of doing this would no be attempting to use a shell builtin, but rather directly modifying the $HISTFILE

```
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history # Or just let the shell decide
for x in `seq $1 $2`
do
  sed "\'$1d\'" $HISTFILE
done
```

Original Answer:

The problem seems to be with running the bash script non-interactively...

[This thread on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112354/history-stops-working-when-run-inside-bash-script) seems to cover a workaround method to get your script working:

```
#!/bin/bash
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history   # Or wherever you bash history file lives
set -o history             # enable history
for x in `seq $1 $2`
do
  history -d $1
done
```

Comment: You can also "run" your script in the current (interactive) shell by using `source` or the bash builtin `.` like so: `source script.sh line1 line2` or `. script.sh line1 line2`.

Comment: I copied and pasted. I tried changing quotes. I tried switching which number was greater. I tripled checked permissions. I'm not getting a positive result.

Comment: @Klik Hmm, yeah, it isn't working for me either, although my comment above works.

Comment: Yes, Seth your solution works for me `source idelhistory3 350 400
` . Perhaps that should be the solution for this thread.

Comment: @Klik Check the edit. Does that work?

Comment: I'm getting this: `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `1'`